# Would a B-tree be more efficient in practice than a binary search tree if B had the same size as a cache line?

Tags: algorithm, search, caching, b-tree

I was wondering whether B trees are only used to speed up applications that depend on data relying on the disk, where an I/O is very expensive to make, or they are also sometimes preferred if you want to create an application that tries to take advantage of the caches that may exist or not in a computer. Has anyone conducted experiments on this, and did B-trees win the binary search trees?

Comment: Yes, in-memory B-trees also tend to be faster than binary search trees. See for example http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2013/01/c-containers-that-save-memory-and-time.html

Comment: I would think this might depend somewhat on the usage patterns. There are probably cases where a BST is faster than a B-tree, and vice versa. Relying on generalizations instead of knowing the characteristics of your exact current problem domain is a frequent source of much bad code... Also note that particular blog post is comparing B-trees with Red-Black trees, which are only one particular subclass of BSTs...